# Moving children items in QGraphisItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsitem

I have an item which is parent of some other items. It is not a group, in fact this item draws a cubic Bezier curve and the children are its control points.

The problem is that moving the children items will result in a geometry change, so I should call parent's `prepareGeometryChange()` when children are moved, but that method is protected.

This is just an example, and in general the question I'm seeking an answer is:

when a `QGraphicsItem` has a geometry that depends on its children, and the children are movable by user interaction, how do I use `prepareGeometryChange()`?

Is it necessary to call it? Is it wrong to build items in this way and use children for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember same issue for myself, I re-implemented

```
QGraphicsItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value)
```

for both children and parent.

When each `change` was a `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` that child emits a signal, and the parent has a corresponding slot.

Comment: And I guess the parent will call `prepareGeometryChange` in that slot, right?

Comment: When you are implementing `itemChange` you have access to `prepareGeometryChange` if it's necessary.

Comment: Ok I got it, the emitted signal is a "Item changed" signal which is delivered to parent, and the parent then prepares for the change. Anyway ok, I thought that it has to be something like that. Thanks